# Error: Java file out of source root

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Estoy usando Gradle y cuando cree el proyecto estaba todo bien, pero ahora no me reconoce la rutas y no tengo claro como hacer esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]